# How can we construct an algorithm in O(V +E) to compute a path that traverses each edge of G exactly once in each direction

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity

Consider connected graph G that is not directed.How can we construct an algorithm in O(V +E) to compute a path that traverses each edge of G exactly once in each direction

Answer (score 1):

A path with that property is called an [Eulerian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path). There's a theorem that says a path like this exists if and only if every node has even degree or there are exactly two nodes of odd degree.

There are many algorithms for constructing Eulerian paths in linear time. The general idea is (usually) to walk around the graph until you get a cycle, then to continuously increase the number of edges in that cycle by extending it using unused edges. You can read more about these algorithms [at this link.](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~rg/book/chap5.pdf)